# Hosting a ruby web on google cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, hosting

How do I deploy a ruby file from git to google cloud.
Is it possible to push a ruby file from github to google cloud,please can  purchase a domain name,how will the ruby file be hosted on  the cloud.

Comment: You might find [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+on+rails+google+cloud) helpful or maybe [this one](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/rails/).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to develop a ruby application on Google Cloud. I would suggest to start by following the [Quickstart for Ruby in the App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/ruby/quickstart).

You can store your app on Cloud Source Repositories and Automate App Engine deployments with Cloud Build [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories).

You can serve your app via a custom domain, such as example.com, instead of the default appspot.com address [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mapping-custom-domains).

Comment: No,i want to use a file from github,it is written in ruby  ,i want to use it to host my website

Comment: Yes,i think,this is best,please can i use free credits for google domains

Comment: To use [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) you need to purchase a new domain, unless you already have one that you want to use [link](https://domains.google/). I do not think you can use free credits from Google Cloud free trial account.